# How do I bundle a third party file to the Webpack output file, so its executed in the global scope, not in a webpack module?

Tags: webpack

Given a simple Webpack configuration like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: 'my_entry.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'my_output.js'
  }
}
```

But I have external third party files JavaScript file called `my_script1.js`, `my_script2.js`, etc, what's the easiest way to append these files to the output file?

Not wrapping it around any module pattern, just simple appending the source into output file (outside the generated modularization code)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry):

> If you pass an array: All modules are loaded upon startup. The last
>   one is exported.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['my_script.js', 'my_entry.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'my_output.js'
  }
}
```

Comment: Would this work if I have two external files I want to bundle? (I will update the original question)

Comment: But when I do that, it looks like the code is wrapped in a webpack module: /***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

console.log("corgrath1");

/***/ }, - the code I need to append needs to be executed in the global space.

Comment: In that case I recommended reading up on options here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html

Comment: I tried that, but its to cryptic to figure out, hence why I created a stackoverflow question =)

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules